# Calculate $x+y$ probabilistically from qbits in state of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x\rangle + |y\rangle)$

Tags: quantum-information

Assuming we have $N$ qbits, it is placed in a composite state that correspond to integer $x$ and $y$: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x\rangle + |y\rangle)$. The actual integer $x$ and $y$ being unknown.

Is it possible to read out integer $x+y$ assuming we have only one copy of these $N$ qbits in such a state?

Also the method of reading out x+y does not need to work every time. If it gives correct result randomly with certain probability then it is fine.

Comment: Do you mean here that $x$ and $y$ are multi-qubit states corresponding to the binary representation of these numbers?

Comment: yes that is correct. Also the method of reading out $x+y$ does not need to work every time. If it gives correct result at certain probability then it is fine.

Comment: Tip: Use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >

Comment: If it is probabilistic: Do you need to know when it gave the correct outcome? -- Also, it would help to add those clarifications to your question.

Comment: No need to know when it gives correct answer. If the correct answer is given randomly with a certain percentage then it meets the requirement.

Comment: Please add it to your question!!

Answer (score 2):

1. It is not possible deterministically, since $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle+2\rangle$ are not orthogonal and thus cannot be distinguished deterministically.
2. It is also not possible probabilistically in an unambiguous way, since the Hilbert space is $n=2^N$-dimensional, but there are $2n-3$ possible outcomes.  However, unambiguous discrimination can only distinguish $n$ outcomes (each outcome projection must be orthogonal to all other states in the space).
3. Clearly, you can do it in a probabilistic ambiguous way, since each outcome corresponds to a different state. Whether this is enough for you is a different matter.

Comment: Point 3 might not be valid since for a pair of specific (x,y) we only have one copy of the qbits. Thus it can only be measured once.

Comment: @wang1908 I don't think my statement was anywhere close to being quantitative enough to qualify as incorrect.  After all, your question was also quite un-quantitative.  But for sure there is a measurement which will yield the correct result with higher probability on the correct input state. Whether this is enough for your purposes, I don't know (as you don't specify them).

Comment: I assumed by "since each outcome corresponds to a different state" you mean to measure same qbits multiple times. I must have misunderstood it.

Comment: @wang1908 Well, there are obviously many *possible* outcomes of the measurement!